# Is it normal that R squared is on the lower side with panel data (DiD) regression?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

I am working on a dataset with over $30000$ observations of bank-specific data (such as net income, total assets etc.) from 2010-2017.

I've been trying to estimate the effects of negative interest rates on bank profitability and used a DiD/panel regression approach for doing so. Additionally, I added typical control variables (such as asset size, type of business model etc.).

While the results have been quite convincing and significant, the R square is very low (around 5%).

I did not find a lot online regarding that issue besides "add more variables". On researchgate there is one older thread in which people state that it is quite common for financial panel data to have lower R-Squared. Is that actually true?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few kinds of R2 in a panel FE context, like within, between, and overall. Can you clarify exactly how the 5% is calculated?

Comment: I just did a normal lm ~ regression in R without using the plm package. I used time dummies and treatment dummies. I guess that its overall then?

Comment: That's not overall, that's just the adjusted R-squared. That does not sound like a complete DID specification to me, so perhaps that is where this is going wrong.